# Create a array inside existing array in Php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have following array and i want to add "image" array inside that array(current array),How can i do this ?

here is my current array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [first_name] => sandeep
            [last_name] => sharma
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [first_name] => Gaurav
            [last_name] => Jain
       )
```

And i want array something like this(want "image array" inside current array)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [first_name] => sandeep
            [last_name] => sharma
            [image] =array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [image] => abc.jpg
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [image] => abcdef.jpg
                        )   
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [first_name] => Gaurav
            [last_name] => Jain
            [image] =array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [image] => abcdefghi.jpg
                        )
                )
       )
```

I tried with following code but its showing image array in last,i want image array inside current array,here is my code

```
$rows = $query->result_array(); //current array
            array_push($rows, array("image"=>$image));  //$image is second array(where image save as array)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach ($rows as $i => $row) {
    $rows[$i]['image'] = $image;
}
```

Please find the demo [here](https://3v4l.org/sKgNa)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to loop your array :

```
foreach ($rows as $i => $row) {
    // $i contains the index, here we push at the end the new array
    $rows[$i][] = ['image' => $image];
}
```

Comment: this doesn't actually get OP desired result - check fiddle https://phpfiddle.tk/83bb5819

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$rowsWithImages = array_map(function ($row) {
    $row['image'] = $image;
    return $row;
}, $rows);
print_r($rowsWithImages);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` with pass by reference

```
foreach($a as &$_v){
  $_v['image'] = $image;
}
```

Live DEMO : https://3v4l.org/VIgYP